# How to load and show window from xib file

Tags: cocoa, xib, swift3, nswindowcontroller, xcode8

I have made a window xib and cocoa class file (nswindowcontroller) and need to show the window from xib with an button action from main window.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post the code you have so far to better help other users understand your exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your main NSWindowController:

In the interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CustomWindowController *windowController;
```

In the implementation:

```
- (IBAction)didPressOpenWindowButton:(id)sender {
    CustomWindowController *wc = [[CustomWindowController alloc] init];
    [wc showWindow:nil];
    [wc.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    _windowController = wc;
}
```

Connect your IBAction to your NSButton in the main window.

Comment: the@property (nonatomic, strong) CustomWindowController *windowController;

Comment: The @property (nonatomic, strong) CustomWindowController *windowController; do not work I am yousing xcode 8, swift 3